# Adding up from a text file and ignoring syntax errors

Tags: java

I am writing a code that adds up numbers from a text file and displays the total. But i want to make it so that if the user enters a word or a decimal number then it ignores it and carries on adding up the next number?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File myFile = new File("Numbers.txt");         
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        int sum=0;        

        while (scan.hasNext()) {         
            sum+= scan.nextInt( );     
        } 
        System.out.println(sum);

        scan.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File myFile = new File("Numbers.txt");         
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        String sum="";        
        int number = 0;
        int total = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext()) { 
            try {
              sum = scan.next();
              number = Integer.parseInt(sum);        
              total += number;
            } catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Unable to parse string !! + " + sum);
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("The total is : " + total);

        scan.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Its not liking the 'String sum=0; '

Answer (score 0):

Use `scan.next()` instead, and wrap a `Integer.parseInt()` around it. Then add a try-catch to catch the `NumberFormatException`s that will occur if `Integer.parseInt()` tries to parse a non integer:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    try {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //If there was a NumberFormatException, do nothing.
    }
} 
System.out.println(sum);
```